# setAttribute issue with if statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I set meta attributes by a sreen size.

```js
    var myViewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");

    function getViewport(e) {
        if (e.matches) {
            myViewport.setAttribute("content", "width=1280, user-scalable=yes");
            console.log("foo");
        } else {
            console.log("bar");
        }
    }

    var mobileViewport = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)");
    getViewport(mobileViewport);
    mobileViewport.addEventListener("change", getViewport);
```

It works if I don't use setAttribute, but if I use setAttribute I see the both "foo" and "Bar" in  the media (max-width:600).

Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: in the setAttribute you set the `width` to `1280` and not to `1280px`, can that be the issue?

Comment: @DarioPiotrowicz it can't be set with the length unit here, only numeric px prefix.

Comment: yeah you're right :(